# Yeoman generator add a new file generated exsiting project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've yeoman generator which generate a simple sproject successfully.

I want that **after** the project generation, in latter time that the use will have the ability to generate a new file `deployment.yaml` under the `app` folder, however it needs to read some data from the main generator
for example `appName` as the sub-generator needs to generate a new file
inside the generated application.

e.g. `yo tdk`

This command generates a new project

And when I run `yo tdk:event` (or something similar) it will generate a new file inside the project `app` folder

For illustration I've created this very simple generator

```
const Generator = require("yeoman-generator");

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    this.props = {
      appName: "my-app",
      srvName: "my-service"
    };

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "appName",
        message: "Project name: ",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.appName
      },
      {
        name: "srvName",
        message: "Service name: ",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.srvName
      }
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("app"),
      this.destinationPath(this.props.appName),
      this.props
    );
  }
};
```

This generator have two simple question

1. app name
2. service name

And it will generate a project like

```
myapp   /root
 -app   /folder
  - service.yaml   /single file at the project generation
```

The generated `service.yaml` looks like following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <%= appName %>
spec:
  selector:
    app: <%= srvName %>
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

Now after the generation of the project with this `service.yaml` file
I want in **latter time** (after the project generation)to add new file `deployment.yaml` under the app folder

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <%= appName %>  //this is the appname from the project generation

spec:
  replicas: <%= replica %>
  selector:
    app: <%= srvName %>
```

The `appName` & `srvName` are coming from the **main generator**,
(I saw that there is option to share data between sub generator 
https://yeoman.io/authoring/storage.html , not sure how to share this between generators ) 
and the `replica` **should come from the new/sub generator**

This is the project structure after the generation

```
myapp   /root
 -app   /folder
  - service.yaml      /single file at the project generation
  - deployment.yaml   / new file added to the project under app folder
```

Like user start another `generator/sub` and have a new question e.g. `how much replicas do you want?` and then generates the file.

How can I do it ?

**update**
This is my project strucutre

```
myapp
 - node_modules
 - package.json //here I declare the main-generator command -> tdk
 - generators
 -- app
 ---index.ts
 --deployment
 ---index.ts
 ---package.json    //here I declare the sub-generator command -> deploy
 - node_modules
 - package.json
 -.yo-rc.json       //here I see the data that I keep via config.set api
```

**Update**

When I call to the sub generator via program like

const yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
const env = yeoman.createEnv();

```
env.lookup(function () {
    env.run("tdk:deploy", {
        replicas: 100
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("done", err);
    });
});
```

**I got error:**

out from config undefined : undefined //the undefind is from the console in the sub-generator

```
done TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1037:7)
```

I put a console.log in the subgenerator code  like

```
  initializing() {
    this.srvName = this.config.get("srvName");
    this.appName = this.config.get("appName");
    console.log("out from config", this.srvName, ":", this.appName);
  }
```

And when I run the subgenerator I got empty config ( from the `.yo-rc.json`) 
while checking the .yo-rc.json . I was able to see the entry from the main generator, the data was stored but when I run it from the program it doesnt find it...any idea ?

This is the link for both project (very basic yeoman generator which demonstrate the point)  just need to run `npm install` for both projects
and for the generator run also `npm link`.

**At the end**: a project should be generated with **two files**

```
1. service.yaml   // generated from the main generator
2. deployment.yaml - // generated from sub generator with the properties from the main & sub generator
```

currently, the `deployment.yaml` file is not generated

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kBnZxpVcRR9qhGZagVtod7W4wFmt73C6

```
1 . generator-tdk -  Generator and sub-generator 
2.  yeomanEnv - The code which is running the sub-generator to create the file inside the generated project
```

What am I doing wrong ?  :(

if there is a way from the sub-generator to read the `.yo-rc.json` , it can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the values to config inside `configuring` of the main generator like this:

```
configuring() {
  this.config.set('appName', this.props.appName);
  this.config.set('srvName', this.props.srvName);
}
```

and read the values inside the sub-generators:

```
initializing() {
  this.srvName = this.config.get("srvName");
  this.appName = this.config.get("appName");
}
```

So you'll have access to these values via `this.srvName` and `this.appName` upon writing.

**Example code:**

app/index.js:

```
const Generator = require("yeoman-generator");

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    this.props = {
      appName: "my-app",
      srvName: "my-service",
    };

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "appName",
        message: "Project name: ",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.appName,
      },
      {
        name: "srvName",
        message: "Service name: ",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.srvName,
      },
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then((props) => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  configuring() {
    this.config.set('appName', this.props.appName);
    this.config.set('srvName', this.props.srvName);
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("app"),
      this.destinationPath(this.props.appName),
      this.props
    );
  }
};
```

deploy/index.js:

```
const Generator = require("yeoman-generator");

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  initializing() {
    this.srvName = this.config.get("srvName");
    this.appName = this.config.get("appName");
  }

  prompting() {
    this.props = {
      replicas: 0,
    };

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "replica",
        message: "how much replicas do you want?",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.replicas,
      },
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then((props) => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("deploy"),
      this.destinationPath(this.appName),
      {
        srvName: this.srvName,
        appName: this.appName,
        ...this.props,
      }
    );
  }
};
```

and commands:

`yo <name` for the main project generation

`yo <name>:deploy` to ask for replicas and create `deployment.yaml`

---

**To execute the sub-generator without the use of `yo`:**

```
var yeoman = require("yeoman-environment");
var env = yeoman.createEnv();

env.lookup(function () {
  env.run("<name>:deploy", {
      replicas: 100
  }, (err) => {
    console.log("done", err);
  });
});
```

and a sample sub-generator that skips question if values are passed via options (`deploy/index.js`):

```
const Generator = require("yeoman-generator");

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  initializing() {
    this.srvName = this.config.get("srvName");
    this.appName = this.config.get("appName");
  }

  prompting() {
    this.props = {
      replicas: 0,
    };

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "replicas",
        message: "which app to generate?",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.replicas,
        when: !this.options.replicas, // disable the question if it's found in options
      },
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then((props) => {
      this.props = props;

      // set values from options (if found)
      this.props.replicas = this.options.replicas || this.props.replicas;
    });
  }


  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("deploy"),
      this.destinationPath(this.appName),
      {
        srvName: this.srvName,
        appName: this.appName,
        ...this.props,
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216265/discussion-on-answer-by-tibebes-m-yeoman-generator-add-a-new-file-generated-exs).